# PYTHON: Handling the KeyError

Tags: python, keyerror, anagram

I was trying to solve a problem (checking if string `s` and `t` are anagram) in Python:

**Algorithm:**
To examine if `t` is a rearrangement of `s`, we can count occurrences of each letter in the two strings and compare them. Since both `s` and `t` contain only letters from `a-z`, a simple counter `table` of size 26 is sufficient.

We could increment the counter for each letter in `s` and decrement the counter for each letter in `t`, then check if the counter reaches back to zero.

**Code:**

```
class Solution:
    def isAnagram(self, s: str, t: str) -> bool:
        
        if len(s) != len(t): 
            return False
        
        table = {} 
        
        for i in range(len(s)):
            table[s[i]] = table.get(table[s[i]], 0) + 1
            
        for i in range(len(t)):
            table[t[i]] = table.get(table[s[i]], 0) - 1
            if table[t[i]] < 0:
                return False
            
        return True
```

Yet, I get a KeyError in the first loop. To handle that, I tried using `.get()` but still cannot tackle.

I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what error you are getting please. What is the traceback?

Comment: Also, what is `table`? Please [edit] to include a [mcve]

Comment: `table[s[i]] = table.get(table[s[i]], ...)` You're trying to access the key in `table` that you're in the process of setting on the right hand side there, and `table` is empty at that point anyway…

Comment: `table[s[i]] = table.get(s[i], 0) + 1`?

Comment: @deadshot Yes, thanks. This fixes the error. But still, the code seems not to work out the problem correctly :)

Comment: also change `table[t[i]] = table.get(t[i], 0) - 1`

Comment: `sorted(t) == sorted(s)`

Answer (score 0):

- While looking for value in `dict`, you lookup twice: `table.get(table[s[i]], 0)`.
- `[]` and `.get()` are synonymous except that latter is **safe when empty** and returns default.
- This should be the loop you'd need. Credits to @deadshot.

```
        for i in range(len(s)):
            table[s[i]] = table.get(s[i], 0) + 1
            
        for i in range(len(t)):
            table[t[i]] = table.get(t[i], 0) - 1
            if table[t[i]] < 0:
                return False
```

Comment: Thanks. Also, `return False if len(s) != len(t) else sorted(s) == sorter(t)` works. I just wanted to fix the abovementioned code :)

Comment: got it. yeah i see the dict lookup has a problem as mentioned by @deadshot.